# Prove the inequality $x(1-y^{1/x}) \le \ln (1/y)$

Tags: inequality

As part of a homework assignment, I have to show that $x(1-y^{1/x}) \le \ln (1/y)$ for positive $x,y$.

I've tried using simple identities like $1-p\le e^{-p}$ but have gotten nowhere. Plugging into Mathematica, I see that the left-hand function is monotonic in x and asymptotically approaches $\ln 1/y$. I can prove monotonicity using calculus, but can't establish the asymptotic bound using L'Hopital's rule.

Is there a better way to establish this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can prove this by using the identity you have mentioned.
put p = 1−y^1/x . 
then its just a few steps.

Answer (score 1):

$$ x(1-y^{1/x})\leq\ln(1/y)\implies (1-y^{1/x})\leq -\ln(y)^{1/x}. $$

Now, let $a=y^{1/x}$ which implies

$$(1-a)\leq -\ln(a)$$

which is true inequality you can prove it by noting that the function $1-a$ is the tangent of the function $-\ln(a)$ at $a=1$ and the function $-\ln(a)$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$ that is the graph lies above the tangent line.